# AVAudioengine play / loop audio , multiple buttons

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I have this button to play and loop a wav. But what if I have a second button with another loop? I want this second loop to start playing once pressed, however, the first loop must finish his 'round'. And vice versa (play and loop the second loop, press button first loop and it takes over)

```
 @IBAction func playButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {



    guard let filePath: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "25loop110", ofType: "wav") else{ return }
          print("\(filePath)")
          let fileURL: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
          guard




              let audioFile = try? AVAudioFile(forReading: fileURL) else{ return }

          let audioFormat = audioFile.processingFormat
          let audioFrameCount = UInt32(audioFile.length)
          guard let audioFileBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFormat, frameCapacity: audioFrameCount)  else{ return }
          do{
              try audioFile.read(into: audioFileBuffer)

              timeShift.rate = adjustedBpm/bpm
              playerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, at: nil, completionHandler: nil)


          } catch{
              print("over")
          }

          try? audioEngine.start()
          playerNode.play()
          playerNode.scheduleBuffer(audioFileBuffer, at: nil, options:.loops,completionHandler: nil)

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this behavior by using the `completionHandler` parameter of `.scheduleBuffer`.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
var nextAudioFilePath: String  
var isPlaying: Bool = false

@IBAction func playLoopA() {  
   guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "audioFileA", ofType: "wav") else { return }  
   nextAudioFilePath = path  
   guard !isPlaying else { return }  
   play()
}  

@IBAction func playLoopB() {  
   guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "audioFileB", ofType: "wav") else { return }  
   nextAudioFilePath = path  
   guard !isPlaying else { return }  
   play()
}  

private func play() {  
   let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: nextAudioFilePath)  
   ...  
   playerNode.scheduleBuffer(audioFileBuffer, at: nil, options: [], completionHandler: { [weak self] in   
      self?.play()
   })
}
```

Comment: Thx Robin, I will look into this!!

Comment: could you maybe explain where I can put different wav url's in this case?

Comment: Your welcome :-)  keep in mind to accept the answer if it solved your problem ;-)

Comment: I have one last question if you don't mind. This is wrong, but I don't know how to change it:

Comment: private func play() {
        
         
          guard let filePath: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "25loop110", ofType: "wav") else{ return }
                print("\(filePath)")
                let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: nextAudioFilePath)
                guard
                    
                        let audioFile = try? AVAudioFile(forReading: fileURL) else{ return }

Comment: You need to remove first line `guard let filePath: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "25loop110", ofType: "wav") else{ return }`, because filePath is now set from outside. But what exactly is wrong?

Comment: ah ok, I will check this and see what happens.

Comment: Ah, great!! You really saved my day. Thnx Robin!!

Answer (score 0):

I also found this solution:

```
playerNode.scheduleBuffer(audioFileBuffer, at: nil, options:[.interruptsAtLoop, .loops],completionHandler: nil)
```